# Stretch the child grid

Tags: wpf, xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StatusBar Height="25" Grid.Row="5">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StatusBarItem Content="Text" FontSize="10" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <StatusBarItem Content="Text" FontSize="10" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <ProgressBar Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2"/>
        </Grid>
    </StatusBar>
</Grid>
```

Please help the beginner.

I want to create a StatusBar and divide it into 3 elements. I want to align the first element on the left side. The second by right. The third in the center.
In the first and second elements I want to locate the text. In the third I want to locate StatusBar.

Why does the grid in StatusBar not want to stretch to the StatusBar and format the elements?
What am I doing wrong?

Sorry for mistakes, if any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the default ItemsPanel of the `StatusBar` won't tell us how much space we have, we need to provide it with one that does (like `grid`).

A possible solution is as follows (using the grid as the ItemsPanel straight away) :

```
    <StatusBar Height="25" Grid.Row="5">
        <StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                </Grid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </StatusBar.ItemsPanel>

        <StatusBarItem Content="Text" FontSize="10" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <StatusBarItem Content="Text" FontSize="10" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <ProgressBar Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2"/>
    </StatusBar>
```

Comment: I'm also not sure if you can just dump a `ProgressBar` into a `StatusBar` without repercussions. if you run into trouble, try wrapping it in a `StatusBarItem`

Comment: also maybe set `HorizontalContentAlignment` !